# Properties of orthogonal projections

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have a question about orthogonal projections on a Hilbert space $H$. Can we say that the range of a projection $P\in B(H)$ is closed? Thus we have to ask if the range is a Hilbert space.

Moreover: Why holds $\Vert P\Vert\leq 1$ and why the if and only if relation: $x\in Im(P)$ if and only if $Px=x$. Does is directly follows that $\Vert Px\Vert=\Vert x\Vert$ and that $Im(P)=\{x\in H: \Vert Px\Vert=\Vert x\Vert\}$.

Should someone help me with this facts?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you define a projection as a linear map $P$ with domain and codomain $H$ such that $P^2 = P$?

Comment: Yes, $P:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ and $P^2=P$.

Comment: Are you dealing with orthogonal projections? $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a projection, but $\|P\| = \sqrt{5}>1$.

Answer (score 2):

So, $P$ is a self-adjoint operator such that $P^2=P$.

1. Why $\operatorname{ran}P=\{x:Px=x\}$? Because the second set is contained in the first, tautologically. The first is contained in the second, because if $x=Py$, then $Px=P^2y=Py=x$.
2. Why is $\operatorname{ran}P$ closed? Because it coincides with the kernel of the operator $I-P$, by part 1.
3. Why $\|P\|\le 1$? Because for all $x$, 
   $$\|Px\|^2=\langle Px,Px\rangle = \langle P^2x,x\rangle=\langle Px,x\rangle \le \|Px\|\|x\| \tag{1}$$
4. Why $\operatorname{ran}P=\{x:\|Px\|=\|x\|\}$? Observe that for every $x$, $Px$ and $x-Px$ are orthogonal:
   $$ \langle Px,x-Px\rangle = \langle P x,x\rangle -\langle Px,Px\rangle =0$$
   using (1). Therefore, $\|x\|^2=\|Px\|^2+\|x-Px\|^2$ holds for all $x$. This identity shows that $\|Px\|=\|x\|$ holds precisely when $x=Px$. Now we are back to part 1.